# Accessing content of all divs having same class name but different xpaths

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract data from two divisions in XHTML having the same class name using python but when I try to take out their xpaths, they are different. I tried using

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name("abc")
print content.text
```

but it gives only the content of first div. I heard this can be done using xpath. The xpaths of the divs are as follows:

```
//*[@id="u_jsonp_2_o"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3] 
//*[@id="tl_unit_-5698935668596454905"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]    
//*[@id="u_jsonp_3_c"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]
```

What I thought, since each xpath has same ending, how can we use this similarity in ending and then access the divisions in python by writing [1],[2],[3].... at the end of the xpath?

Also, I want make content an array containing all the content of classes named `abc`. Moreover, I don't know how many `abc`s exist! How to integrate the data of all of them in one content array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it doesn't matter if you use class name or css, you are only searching for "one" element with `find_element` but you want to find several elements:

you need to use `find_element**s**_by_class_name`

```
content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("abc")
for element in content:
  // here you can work with every single element that has class "abc"
  // do whatever you want
  print element.text
```

Comment: The answer looks perfect but still, the edited code on my machine is returning only one entry, although i see that type(content) is a list now.

Comment: please post your HTML where I can see the different elements with their class-attibutes. thx

Comment: I want to access all the posts of my timeline. It is actually showing only one div with the name '_1dwg' in the source file but there are many. Should i post my script here so that you can run it with your id / password and see whats happening?

Comment: Here is the python file. Edit the file and add your username and password and run it . https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9q9YK3qNDvxbW1QbnhXdGRuZTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no, I mean, please post the relevant HTML in your question, this might be helpful for others as well

Comment: I was opening my facebook id through script. I think i should use implicit/explicit wait to let the page load. Figuring out the solution myself :)

Comment: @PrabhjotRai Is is a vital policy on Stackoverflow that you post all essential information (in this case, the HTML document in question) here, instead of linking to an off-site resource. If you don't, it is likely that the question will be closed.

Comment: so how do i share my code if its quite big? It's tedious for me too, to make a file then upload and share the link.

Comment: @PrabhjotRai You don't. Instead, you minimize the code and isolate the problem to be able to post a small, self-contained example, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @drkthng The problem is solved. Actually I was not waiting for the page to load properly, neither scrolling the whole webpage till the end of the document to load the page fully. Thanks for the shortcut to create a list of all the elements. :)